# Printing "x" number of sheets based on cell value on master sheet

Tags: excel, vba, printing

I am attempting to use vba to print a certain number of copies of different sheets in my workbook by adding a number to column D.  I have the following code for this but i can't get it to work.
I have screen grabbed a picture of an example workbook for this.

```
Sub PrintSheets()
    Dim mysheets As Range
    For Each mysheets In Sheet1.Range("A5:A100")
    If mysheets.Offset(0, 3).Value <> "" Then Sheets(mysheets.Value).PrintOut Copies:=mysheets.Offset(0, 3).Value
    Next mysheets
End Sub
```

[image]

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: Please post the error displayed by the VBE. And on which line does it happen. Is your default printer a "Print to PDF" type? If the printing is done on paper, your code seems to work correctly. In a 'PDF printer' you will have to configure/handle (different) naming for each copy (if the device allows it), as it will probably ask the user for a name and save location for each file (like experienced here). There are several threads here on SO addressing this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet

Set Sheet1 = Worksheets(1) 'or Worksheets("Sheet1")'
```

If statements need to finish with End if. eg:

If xxx then

do this

End If

Comment: The `IF-Then-[Else]` instruction is coded correctly. It must have an 'End If' only when using 'block' mode. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ifthenelse-statement. No need to add your code suggestion as the sheets are being addressed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find some code that did the trick.

I ended up linking each sheet to the respective master sheet and adding the number of copies needed there.

Probably not the cleanest as it would be nice to not have to link the sheets to the master but it works.

Sub PrintLabels()
Dim xSh As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

```
On Error Resume Next

For Each xSh In Worksheets
    xSh.Select
    Call RunCode
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Worksheets("Master").Select
```

End Sub
Sub RunCode()

```
    If Range("H1") > 0 Then
    ActiveSheet.PrintOut Copies:=Range("H1").Value
    End If
```

End Sub